# Groovy list contains method on [x..y]

Tags: groovy

```
[1..4].contains(2)

===> false


[1,2,3,4].contains(2)

===> true
```

Why the first code snippet returns false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common mistake, that gets everybody at least once

This isn't a range, it's a list containing a range

```
[1..4]
```

Notice the square brackets.

What you need is regular brackets:

```
(1..4).contains(2)
```

Which will give you the result you expect